# OpenOffice Calc to xml (with arrays)

Tags: xml, xslt, filter, export, xls

I'm trying to automatically convert an .xls file (OpenOffice Calc) with the following structure

```
ID  |  Param1   |  Param2   |  ArrayValue1  |  ArrayValue2  |  ArrayValue3  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
0   |    HI     |   Bye     |      0        |       1       |       2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  Hello    |   Cya     |               |               |       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Into an .xml file with the following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Collection>
   <Items>
      <Item>
         <ID>0</ID>
         <Param1>Hi</Param2>
         <Param2>Bye</Param3>
         <Array type="array"> 
             <ArrayValue1>0</ArrayValue1>
             <ArrayValue2>1</ArrayValue2>
             <ArrayValue3>2</ArrayValue3>
         </Array> 
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <ID>1</ID>
         <Param1>Hello</Param2>
         <Param2>Cya</Param3>
         <Array type="array"> 
         </Array> 
      </Item>
   </Items>
</Collection>
```

I also have one restriction: the 'ArrayValue#' lines should not appear if the corresponding cells are empty (as shown in the example), but the Array parameter should always appear.

I'm new with this kind of data treatment and I've been trying to adapt some xslt filters doing similar things to achieve this, but I failed every time. (For example, I tried to use this export filter: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=3490)

I'll appreciate if any of you can help me with this issue as it is taking me a lot of time to solve it.

Thank you very much in advance.

PS: I'm trying something like this, but I think I am far from the real solution :(

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//table:table">
        <Collection>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </Collection>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

```
<Items>
    <xsl:for-each select="table:table-row">
        <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">

            <Item>

                <xsl:for-each select="table:table-column">
                    <xsl:if test="position() &eq; 1">
                        <ID> <!-- Get value here --> </ID>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="position() &eq; 2">
                        <Param1> <!-- Get value here --> </Param1>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="position() &eq; 3">
                        <Param2> <!-- Get value here --> </Param2>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="position() &eq; 4">
                        <Array type = "array"> 
                        <!-- If cell value is not null -->
                        <ArrayValue1><!-- Get value here --></ArrayValue1>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="position() &eq; 5">
                        <!-- If cell value is not null -->
                        <ArrayValue2><!-- Get value here --></ArrayValue2>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="position() &eq; 6">
                        <!-- If cell value is not null -->
                        <ArrayValue3><!-- Get value here --></ArrayValue3>

                        </Array>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </Item>

        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</Items>
```

Cya!

Comment: It would help if you can provide some code snippets from the xslt you have already tried, and potential results from it that are incorrect.

Comment: Hi @OvidiuDolha thanks for your response. I added some test code to the question above to show what i'm trying. But I think i'm not even close from the solution. :(